Wordpress Custom Column for Attribute Terms Color extra info
In wordpress with woocommerce plugin, I manage to add custom column to attribute. Column is "hex code" which displays the
terms' color hex code. It displays ok. But there is also extra square color displayed after it (please see picture below).
I need to remove that square box under the hex code in column "hex code".
THANKS
function add_hex_code_column( $columns ) {
    unset($columns['hexcode']);  
    $columns['hexcode'] = 'Hex Code';
    return $columns;
}
add_filter( 'manage_edit-pa_vlove-color_columns', 'add_hex_code_column' );

function add_hex_code_column_content( $content, $column, $term_id  ) {
    
    $content = null;
    
    switch ( $column ) {
        case 'hexcode':
            $content = get_term_meta( $term_id, 'st-color-swatch' )[0][0];
            echo '<span><strong>'. $content .'</strong></span>';
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    return $content;
}
add_filter( 'manage_pa_vlove-color_custom_column', 'add_hex_code_column_content', 10, 3 );



That square should be generated by $content = get_term_meta( $term_id, 'st-color-swatch' )[0][0]; so please cross check by using var_dump if you are getting that square from this then you need to find single value (HEX code) from this.
Also this can be done by inspecting the square box and checking it's CSS class and add the CSS accordingly.
Suppose that square has class sqare-dev then CSS code will be .square-dev{display:none;}

Thanks Narendra for the suggestion of "display:none". I was able to not display the square box by adding a css: tr.level-0 > td.hexcode.column-hexcode > div {display:none}

Glad to know it works for you.
